# Rails: update downloads counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem refreshing the downloads counter after sending files. I have a list of files to download and when a user click the link, I want to send the file to him, send the information to database and refresh the downloads counter.

Now I have:

**_file.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Download", files_download_path(file)%> # link to download
....
<%= current_user.downloads_left %>  # my counter
```

**files_controller.rb**

```
def download
   @file = File.find(params[:id])
   Download.find_or_create_by(user: current_user, file: @file)
   redirect_to(@file.file.url)
end
```

**user.rb**

```
def downloads_left
    plan.limit - self.this_month_downloads.size
end
```

And how in simple way update the counter after a user click the link.

The technologies I am using

- Rails 4.2.1
- Ruby 2.2.2

Comment: What exactly doesn't work or what piece of code you didn't write and wonder to know how to do that?

Comment: now the counter are updating after refresh the page, it should be update when user click the link.
I created   `<script type="text/javascript">
                  $("#file").click(function() {
                      window.location=('<%= files_download_path(file) %>');
                  });
              </script>` in the _file.html.erb js -  and added  `current_user.downloads.reload` in the controller but it sometimes works sometimes not :(